# What's wrong with max values of GotoXY function?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, crt

My code is doing strange thing when `MoveMessage` procedure takes max values(`ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight`). So the "Hello, world" string moves to the right down corner and doing strange thing, but the max and min values are set correctly.

Can someone tell me where is my mistake.

```
program HelloCrt;
uses crt;

const
  Message = 'Hello, world!';

  procedure GetKey(var code: integer);
  var
    c: char;

  begin
    c := Readkey;
    
    if c = #0 then
    begin
      c := Readkey;
      code := -ord(c);
    end
    else
      code := ord(c);
  end;

  procedure ShowMessage(x, y: integer; msg: string);
  begin
    GotoXY(x, y);
    write(msg);
    GotoXY(1, 1);
  end;

  procedure HideMessage(x, y: integer; msg: string);
  var
    len, i: integer;

  begin
    len := Length(msg);
    GotoXY(x, y);

    for i := 1 to len do
      write(' ');

    GotoXY(1, 1);
  end;

  procedure MoveMessage(var x, y: integer; msg: string; dx, dy: integer);
  begin
    HideMessage(x, y, msg);
    x := x + dx;
    y := y + dy;

    if x > (ScreenWidth - length(msg)) then
      x := (ScreenWidth - length(msg) + 1);

    if x < 1 then 
      x := 1;

    if y > ScreenHeight then 
      y := ScreenHeight;

    if y < 1 then 
      y := 1;

    ShowMessage(x, y, msg);
  end;

var
  CurX, CurY: integer;
  c: integer;

begin
  clrscr;
  CurX := (ScreenWidth - length(Message)) div 2;
  CurY := ScreenHeight div 2;
  ShowMessage(CurX, CurY, Message);

  while true do
  begin
    Getkey(c);

    if c > 0 then
      break;

    case c of
      -75:
        MoveMessage(CurX, CurY, Message, -1, 0);
      -77:
        MoveMessage(CurX, CurY, Message, 1, 0);
      -72:
        MoveMessage(CurX, CurY, Message, 0, -1);
      -80:
        MoveMessage(CurX, CurY, Message, 0, 1);
    end
  end;

  clrscr;

end.
```

Comment: _"and doing strange thing"_. Please elaborate on exactly what you mean by this.

Comment: @Michael, Its hard to, the "hello world" moves to right down corner and cant be exactly in the corner, when you tries to move it , it doing strange thing

Comment: @KatemeHebi: If you mean that the screen shifts up a line when you `write` to the lower right-hand corner of the screen, then that's just how it works in `crt`-land, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error: maybe like you said, if I got it right. but how can i fix that?

Comment: Note aside: "if x > (ScreenWidth - length(msg)) then x := (ScreenWidth - length(msg) + 1);" is not correct...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: how it must be?

Comment: The test says "if x > K then x := K+1" (where K is width-length). It is a contradiction.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: I dont understand you

Comment: What don't you understand? The `+ 1` is wrong - it takes you past the edge of the screen, which is causing the scrolling you're describing. Your code is saying `if X > MaxAllowed then X := MaxAllowed + 1`, which clearly makes no sense - why would you **add** to `X` when it's already **greater than  the maximum allowed**? Delete the `+ 1`, so that the logic is `if X > MaxAllowed then X := MaxAllowed`.

Comment: To be more precise, I can't say that "if x > K then x := K+1" is wrong. In other contexts it could have sense - not in this one, as @KenWhite says. Suppose you print a single char at column 80: if x{80} > Width{80} - len{1} --> 80 > 79 is true. First problem here (it is legitimate to put 1 char at column 80: the test should be false). But then, you do x := width{80}-len{1}+1 --> 80! The value of x remains the same, so this line of code, in this context, seems (is) wrong.

Comment: It is legitimate to put 1 char at column 80, I said. But if you do that on line 25 (the last line of the screen) maybe the screen scrolls up, (probably) because the cursor must go one position after the last printed char. So you can decide to treat differently the last line or, instead, never print to column 80. Neither solutions are beautiful, I know...